# Handle offline page resources from sub directories

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a PWA testing it on localhost Xampp server. Here's my folder structure

```
/
  |- css
  |   |- style.css
  |- sub
  |   |- other.html
  |- index.html
  |- manifest.webmanifest
  |- service-worker.js
  |- offline.html
```

offline.html has a link to css file `css/style.css` in the head tag. When I'm at the URL **localhost/index.html** and I go offline, the offline page loads perfectly. But when I go to **localhost/sub/other.html** and go offline, the style.css can not load (it is cached).

The browser is looking for the file in `localhost/sub/css/style.css`. So I guess the location in offline.html for style.css needs to be `../css/style.css`.

How do I handle this location problem with sub directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents of your `/offline.html` file are used to fulfill offline navigations for any arbitrary URL, you've got two options to ensure that your subresources are loaded properly:

- Always use absolute URLs when specifying the `src` or `href` of subresources. In other words, use `<link href="/css/style.css" ...>` instead of `<link href="css/style.css" ...>`.
- Add a [`<base href="/">` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) to your `offline.html` HTML, which will cause all subresource URLs to be resolved relative to `/`.